# Subset models in auto.arima function in forecast package

Tags: r, arima, forecasting

I wanted to ask whether it was possible to use the auto.arima function to identify subset ARIMA models rather than those of pure lags? I have identified a model in Stata in subset lags that performs well and wanted to cross check this with the `auto.arima()` function but I can't seem to figure out if subset lags are supported.

Answer (score 4):

No, `auto.arima()` does not allow for subset models. The [FitAR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FitAR/index.html) will automatically do subset AR modelling. I don't know of any R package that does automatic subset ARMA modelling. You can do manual subsetting, of course, with the `arima()` command in R by setting some coefficients to zero using the `fixed` argument -- see the [help file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html) for details.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I wanted to enquire after reading this paper http://goo.gl/x8D3f on subset model selection. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @Brandon Please, register your account and consider accepting this answer (green check mark).