# Why only full ARIMA models in auto.arima?

Tags: r, forecasting, model-selection, arima

It seems that the `auto.arima` function in the "forecast" package in R only considers full ARIMA models. By "full" I mean that if an AR lag $k$ is included, AR lag $j$ will also be included for $k>1$, $0<j<k$ (and the same with MA in place of AR). This was claimed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26668/subset-models-in-auto-arima-function-in-forecast-package) by the author of the `auto.arima` function himself.

I am interested in non-full (restricted) ARIMA models, e.g. an AR(2) model where the first AR lag is restricted to zero: $x_t=\varphi_2 x_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t$.

**Question 1:** Is there a good **theoretical** reason for not considering the non-full ARIMA models?

**Question 2:** Is there a good **practical** reason for not considering the non-full ARIMA models? (Besides the argument of high computational burden if all sub-models within given maximum AR and MA orders are to be estimated.)

Comment: I think the answer to the linked question is a bit misleading because (and the answer even states this) you can fit non-full ARIMAs using the `fixed` parameter.

Comment: @Benjamin: Thanks, I noticed that. However, it is a bit tedious (although certainly possible) to program a search over all subset models. I wonder why it has not been done so far and is not an option in `auto.arima()`. Perhaps there are good reasons?